# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TEST_PKG" when expecting one of the following: ;

Tags: java, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am getting this error

> Errors: check compiler log 6/3            PLS-00103: Encountered the
>   symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:language
>
> 17/1           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member
>   constructor map The symbol "static" was substituted for "PROCEDURE" to
>   continue.
>
> 27/5           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TEST_PKG" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> ;.

Please anyone can help.

```
SET serveroutput ON SIZE 10000;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION test_item_fcn(item_name in varchar2) 
     RETURN BOOLEAN
     AS
  BEGIN
  for c1 in (select * from test_item_ref where test_item_ref.item_id = item_name and rownum = 1) loop
    res := true;
    exit; -- only care about one record, so exit.
  end loop;
  return( res );
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
  END test_item_fcn;

PROCEDURE test_PROC1(p_string IN VARCHAR2) 
  AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Output: ' || TO_CHAR(test_item_fcn(p_string)));

  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
  END test_PROC1;

END test_pkg;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle packages contsist of 2 parts - `PACKAGE` and `PACKAGE BODY`. You should define only functions/procedures headers in the `PACKAGE`. And the `PACKAGE BODY` will contain implementation.

So your code is more like `PACKAGE BODY` specification - just use `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg`.

But before that - create `PACKAGE` specification like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION test_item_fcn(item_name in varchar2) 
     RETURN BOOLEAN;

  PROCEDURE test_PROC1(p_string IN VARCHAR2);

END test_pkg;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION test_item_fcn(item_name in varchar2) 
     RETURN BOOLEAN
     AS
  BEGIN
  for c1 in (select * from test_item_ref where test_item_ref.item_id = item_name and rownum = 1) loop
    res := true;
    exit; -- only care about one record, so exit.
  end loop;
  return( res );
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
  END test_item_fcn;

PROCEDURE test_PROC1(p_string IN VARCHAR2) 
  AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Output: ' || TO_CHAR(test_item_fcn(p_string)));

  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
  END test_PROC1;

END test_pkg;
/
```